# Let $F$ a field and $F^{alg}$ it algebraic closure. If $E/F$ is algebraic, does $E^{alg}=F^{alg}$ or not?

Tags: field-theory

Let $F$ a field and $F^{alg}$ it algebraic closure. If $E/F$ is algebraic, does $E^{alg}=F^{alg}$ or not ? I would say yes, since every polynomial on $E$ split over $K^{alg}$ (since $E\subset K^{alg}$). Therefore $E^{alg}\subset K^{alg}$. The fact that $K^{alg}\subset E^{alg}$ looks natural, but I don't know how to prove it.

As you can see it doesn't look very rigorous. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F^{alg}$ is an algebraic extension of $E$ by the transitivity property of algebraic extension ($F$ an algebraic extension of $E$ and $F^{alg}$ an algebraic extension of $F$ implies $F^{alg}$ an algebraic extension of $E$). $F^{alg}/E$ is also algebraically closed since $E[X]\subset F[X]$. This implies that $F^{alg}$ is the algebraic closure of $E$ since the algebraic closure of $E$ is the unique (up to isomorphism) algebraic extension which is algebraically close.